# Query to update row which contains maximum column value in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table similar to below:

```
C1   C2  C3
A     5   0
A    15   0
A     2   0
B     5   0
B     8   0
```

Result table updates C3 with 1 for mac value of C2 group by C1

```
C1   C2  C3
A     5   0
A    15   1
A     2   0
B     5   0
B     8   1
```

Comment: any sql developed yet ? by you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            MAX(C2) OVER(PARTITION BY C1) MaxC2
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET C3 = CASE WHEN MaxC2 = C2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Supossing table is named `table_name`

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.C3 = 1
FROM table_name as t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT C1, MAX(C2) AS C2 FROM table_name GROUP BY C1
) AS t2 ON t1.C1 = t2.C1 AND t1.C2 = t2.C2
```